# Unable to read PsLoadedModuleList when using Windbg with Qemu

Tags: windbg, qemu, bsod

Using Windbg with Qemu. I have set up Windows like this:

[image: Setting Up Target OS for Debugging]

(1)Launched the Host OS with serial connection options:
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1024 -drive file=host_win-target.img -serial tcp::4445,server,nowait

(2)Launch the Target OS.
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 1024 -drive file=win-target.img -serial tcp:127.0.0.1:4445

Scneario:
Inside the Host OS,execute windbg with serial Com Mode.

The first time connection is made successful
After doing a restart of target OS,i randomly get below error:

[image: Error Prompted on Windbg Tool after restarting Target OS]

After the error the Target OS would take alot of time to boot up,
and the Windbg running on Host OS doesnot gets connected to TargetOS during kernel debug mode.

If some way has faced this issue and has a workaround for it then please share the information for this

Comment: Please [do not upload code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Do you have a solution for this issue?

Comment: Sorry, I hardly do kernel debugging